# Deciding if a mapping is an isomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having trouble with this. I don't think it's an isomorphism, but I'm not certain.

$\langle M_2(R),*\rangle$ with $\langle R,*\rangle$
 where $\phi(A)$ is the determinant of matrix A.

So, the mapping is all 2x2 matrices with real inputs into all real outputs, correct? The operation is multiplication, so is this saying that when you multiply two 2x2 matrices together you expect to get a real determinant?

Can someone please explain this in a way that even I can understand? Thanks.

Comment: No, it is saying the the product of the determinants is the same as the determinant of the product. That is, $\phi(A)\phi(B) = \phi(AB)$.

Comment: To decide whether it is an isomorphism or not, think if it is possible for two different  $2\times 2$ matrices to have the same determinant.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that for it to be an isomorphism, it must be a homomorphism, and a bijection. That is to say, it must be surjective and injective.

Given that, can you think of two non equal matrices that have the same determinant? If so, then what can you conclude about the mapping?

Edit: As Display name points out, ⟨M2(R),∗⟩ is not a group. When answering, I made the assumption that the question was referring to a map between two monoids.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that $M_2(\Bbb{R})$ is not even a group! So group homomorphisms do not even exist! But if it is a homomorphism of $GL_2(\Bbb{R})$, then TASPlasma's answer applies.